# How to Compile Pulse Audio in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, pulse-audio

I want to create a virtual mic in Windows 10. Please help me on how to build and compile Pulse Audio in Windows 10.

Thanks in advance,

Yugesh.

Comment: Specify your version of Windows by editing your question in order to help people answer it.

Comment: it is for windows 10 laptop